# Has anyone used the speech driven animation and can you make it work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, artificial-intelligence

I'm talking about [this repo](http://github.com/DinoMan/speech-driven-animation). I installed all the dependencies but I can't make it work. Any help is highly appreciated (:

I'm running python 3.7.5.

This is my code:

```py
import sda
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
from PIL import Image

va = sda.VideoAnimator(gpu=0, model_path="crema")# Instantiate the animator
fs, audio_clip = wav.read("example/audio.wav")
still_frame = Image.open("example/image.bmp")
vid, aud = va(frame, audio_clip, fs=fs)
va.save_video(vid, aud, "generated.mp4")
```

Sadly it doesn't seem to work and it gives me this error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 170
    warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\test\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    vid, aud = va(frame, audio_clip, fs=fs)
NameError: name 'frame' is not defined
```

Spent about 2 hours and I can't do anything, I'm out of ideas.
If you take the time to help me thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: I think `frame` should be `still_frame`?

Answer (score 0):

1. fix the variable name `frame` or `still_frame`
2. fix `RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work`
   https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/348
3. fix `AttributeError: 'BmpImageFile' object has no attribute 'ndim'`
   https://github.com/DinoMan/speech-driven-animation/issues/11